# Gtkmm program compiles fine but crashes - windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, gtkmm

I have recently installed gtkmm (gtkmm-2.4)

when I compile with g++ I use the following information from  pkg-config

*headerfiles*

```
pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags
```

*objectfiles*

```
pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs
```

So i compile I simple helloworld problam that is to show a window on the screen ...

```
g++ gtkmm_app2.cpp -o gtkmm_app2 `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

It compiles fine but when I execute the program it chrashes. I get the following information:

***An unhandled win32 exception occurred in gtkmm_app2.exe[5364]***

I am not an exert on debugging but when I get redirected to Visual Studio the problems seems to point to a dll-file:

```
 libglibmm-2.4-1.dll
```

---

Information about versions and platforms

Compiler:

```
GNU C++ Compiler: 3.4.5-20060117-3
GNU C++ Compiler Runtime Library: 4.7.2-1
```

OS:

```
 Windows XP Home Edition 2002 (Sevice Pack 3)
```

---

***So My Question: I have no idea what the problems depends on? Could it be the version of MinGw? Or is it the Operating system causing the problem? I can compile and execute without problems using GTK3 on my C-apps, but NOT gtkmm with c++. Any Ideas how to solve the problem(s)? Extremely helpful for help this!!!***

==========================================================================

***The call stack***

```
libglibmm-2.4-1.dll!6652ea89() // it points here ..
libglibmm-2.4-1.dll!664de158()  
msvcrt.dll!77c2a52e()   
msvcrt.dll!77c29d60()   
msvcrt.dll!77c24e2f()   
msvcrt.dll!77c24e42()   
libgtkmm-2.4-1.dll!0069004d()   
libgtkmm-2.4-1.dll!005f0073()
```

*And output in the consolewindow: It seems to be some kind if heapcorruption or segmentation fault:*

```
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\cygwin\home\Ägaren\gtkmm_app2.exe', Binary was not built  with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the  PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libglibmm-2.4-1.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\intl.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2help.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libgthread-2.0-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libsigc-2.0-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\gtkmm\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.

......  
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'gtkmm_app2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Unhandled exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
First-chance exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
Unhandled exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
First-chance exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
Unhandled exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
First-chance exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation   writing location 0x00405068.
Unhandled exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
First-chance exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00405068.
.......
Unhandled exception at 0x6652ea89 in gtkmm_app2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
The program '[5596] gtkmm_app2.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

***EDIT***: I succeeded in compiling and execute the app with VC++ (Visual Studio 2010) so it must be MinGW that is responsible for the crash. But I would really like to know WHAT it is that cause the problem and HOW to solve it.

**EDIT2:** after recompiling with debug support I got this info in cygwing terminalwindow

```
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `main':
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:5: undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::Main(int&,  char**&, bool)'
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:7: undefined reference to   `Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)'
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:9: undefined reference to  `Gtk::Main::run(Gtk::Window&)'
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::~Window()'
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::~Main()'
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::~Window()'
C:\cygwin\home\▒garen/gtkmm_app.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Gtk::Main::~Main()'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `_tcf_0':
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:41: undefined reference to  `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `_tcf_1':
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:42: undefined reference to  `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `_tcf_2':
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:43: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `_tcf_3':
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:44: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `_tcf_4':
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:45: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o:C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:46: more undefined references to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()' follow
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:41: undefined reference to  `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:42: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:43: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:44: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:45: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccIK3N1q.o:C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:46: more   undefined references to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

As I mentioned in the first edit is that I can compile and execute with VC++ in Visual Studio 2010 without problem. So what is the problem then?

Comment: Recompile with debug support; let program crash and then update your question with where/why it crashes.  `g++ -O0 -ggdb gtkmm_app2.cpp -o gtkmm_app2 'pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs'`

Comment: What compiler was used to compile gtkmm? It's possible that there's different ABI.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you able to fix it? I'm using gtkmm 2.22 and mingw32 on x86 machine

Answer (score 1):

Now that I see the debug output, I believe your problem is the order of your compile flags.  I would try:

```
g++ -Wall -g `pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-2.4` gtkmm_app2.cpp -o gtkmm_app2 `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-2.4`
```

The syntax:

```
`pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

should not be used.  It'll compile but not link to the external gtkmm libraries.

Comment: it didnt work - but I use the output of the pkg-config that I paste into the syntax. I have to do this since cygqin for some reason doesnt accept my arguments with backticks. It says "invalid argument. My solution is not beautiful but it should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need separate binaries for mingw and msvc. If you use mingw, you should use gtkmm that has been compiled with mingw. mixing compilers doesnt work very well.